# Setting azure build permissions to push to shared feed

Tags: azure-pipelines

I created a new project in Azure and use my usual shared template for the build but was dismayed to find that it did not push packages to the shared feed -- some security nonsense.

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User '1...' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: ...)).
```

I got it to run by going to the feed setings *Permissions* tab and clicking the *Allow project-scoped builds* button which added a row called `My New Project Name Build Service` to the list.

But there isn't a corresponding entry for all of the other projects. Therefore my new project must be set up wrong.

I notice there is a row called `Project Collection Build Service (Company Name)`. I guess I'm supposed to make my project use that? How?